# Why do we use "the" if we're talking in a general way

Tags: articles

Why do we use 'the' article in such a situation if we're talking about a bell in a school in a general way ... I've thought like it's the bell we don't even know at that time. Could you clarify this aspect for me, please?

> Then **the bell** rings, and they give you **a carton of milk** and **a piece of paper** that says you can go take a dump or something

Comment: It's not just a generic bell that someone rings, it's the specific bell associated with the school. I think there are similar questions but searching "the" isn't easy...

Comment: We _do_ know it, because in a school a bell is commonly used to mark the end of lessons etc.

Comment: _The_ does not have a meaning, and it is not used only for specific definite things, as you have apparently been taught. _The_ is part of the grammar, not the lexicon, and it has as many uses and idioms in English as a gear has uses in a machine.

Answer (score 1):

It would be correct to write "Then a bell rings . . .". In that case, the reader would presumably have no idea about which bell was meant.

However, a school will often have a bell that rings to indicate the start and end of classes. Because the author refers to that specific bell, he or she uses the definite article.